Geting the setting value of Pen and Windows Ink using Powershell
How can I get these data using Powershell?
enter image description here
All I can find from internet are scripts that goes to the Registry Editor which just displays the basic information.
For example:
$windowsPenSettings = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Pen"
and the output will be:
PenArbitrationType PSPath                                                                                                         PSParentPath

             3 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Pen Microsoft.PowerS...

It's not the actual setting like the one in the image

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
